# How to upload file from my App to google drive account using Kotlin(Working in 8.0)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a app(when i click the share button export file to send to google drive account ) and i need to **export the file** from my app the file is **txt** format. Then i need to upload the file to **google drive** 
account using my app.My app developed in **Kotlin** language.

below the code was i tried

```
val sendIntent = Intent().apply {
                        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, keyJSON)
                        setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs")
                        type = "text/plain"
                    }
                    startActivity(sendIntent)
                    true
```

this code working perfectly in Android OS 7, and 8.1. It does not working in Android 4.0 to 6.0 versions.Thanks in advance